# SQL request from Within PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a submit button that the user clicks after entering an email address. The email address should then be sent to a database. I am not sure why this is not working.

A database connection is established and tested beforehand. The file has a php extension. No error messages were received, but no data is uploaded to the database.

```
<form action='' method="post">
    <label>Email Address</label>

    <input type="text" name = "emailaddress" />

   <?php
     if ($_POST["emailaddress"] != "" && $_POST["emailaddress"] != null) {
       $youremail = $_POST["emailaddress"];
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_table (emailAddress) VALUES ('".$youremail."')");

       Print"Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
     }
   ?>

  <input type="submit" value="Add Email">

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What errors do you get?

Comment: is your file with `.php` extension?

Comment: Do you even have a database connection defined? Are you getting error messages? If yes, which?

Comment: You have no connection to the database

Comment: 1. Your database connection ? -- 
2. your form action ? --
3. Your tr/td are not into any table... -- 
4. You should also look at prepared statements...

Comment: database connection is established and tested beforehand.

Comment: file is with a php extension

Comment: no errors gotten - but no information is actually reflected in the database

Comment: try if/else around your mysql_query statement then^^ to check if it's ok or not. Are you sure you do not have other columns that do not accept null values for example, in your table? or just echo your mysql statement to see if it returns error... and what it returns... check your db manager log...

Comment: Is database connection tested ?

Comment: db connection is tested and 100% works

Comment: $result = mysql_query(/*YOUR QUERY*/);
if (!$result) {
 die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: echoing the mysql statement returns 1

Comment: so, it looks like your query is working fine. ^^

Comment: but i don't actually have my db updated

Comment: also, before i even input any email address, i see a 1 to indicate the query was successful